# Image charge method

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, potential, boundary-conditions, method-of-images

First of all, I'm Korean so I'm not good at English.

I'm studying on griffiths electrodynamics.

In Part.3, when calculating electrical potential above the infinite conductor plane, why the boundary condition that the book says make solution unique?

$$
\text{the boundary condition in the book :}
\\.
\\.
\\.
\\ \text{if }z=0\text{ then }V=0 \quad \text{ (V is electrical potential)}
\\ \text{if }x^2 +y^2 +z^2 \gg d^2 \text{then } V \rightarrow 0
$$

How can I know that two conditions are boundary condition?

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE! Firstly, Possion's equation (which is what you are solving in electrostatics) is determined given the charge distribution in a region and the boundary of that region. You could read Poisson's Uniqueness Theorem from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_theorem_for_Poisson%27s_equation). I think Griffiths has it for Laplace's equation only, but it should be essentially the same. Secondly, I don't understandwhat do you mean by "How can I know that two conditions are boundary condition?"

Answer (score 0):

Electric potential is the amount of work per unit charge, to move a unit charge to the position of interest from the point defined as V=0. Sometimes that reference location is infinity, so V is the work per unit charge to move a unit charge from infinity to wherever youre measuring the V.

But it seems in your problem they are defining that reference point as the surface of the plate? (Either that, or they are basically saying the plate has no charge so there is no field and no work to bring a unit charge to there, but I doubt is this)